# PHP: How does Trivago, Hotelscombined get data faster

Tags: php, api, cron

Hello everyone greetings, I am developing website which is similar to Trivago and Hotelscombined. I am able to get the data from all apis like expedia, skoosh, lateroom, getaroom, venere, hotel pronto. I am stuck at the point where I have to maintain the performance of the website. I want to know how to make the website faster just like http://www.trivago.com , http://hotelscombined.com.

How to work with pagination and compare the prices with all apis together.
If I have a cron job running and saving the data in the database then it would be easier for me to show the prices of all the apis and compare them and it will be faster. But it is the bad idea for me to run the cron job, specially when we are talking about hotels api because the content changes every time for hotels.
**Problem with the cron is that, there are thousand of cities, how much data should be fetched in the database and how many times because hotels are booked in next 1 hour approx** . If we run the cron job, and suppose hotel was booked which was fetched and saved in the database, in that case how should i manage this. If cron is the answer to the question then how should we fetch 10 to 20 apis data containing hotels description, images etc in the database and manage them because there are over 1 million hotels in the world or may be more than 10 million. Also there are Cases such as:

i) Search for hotel in New York for 2 adults, 1 children from 1st August check in time till 8th August check out time.

ii) Search for hotel in London for 1 adults, 2 children from 2nd August check in time till 5th August check out time.
And there can be many cases in search. So how many times and for how many cases we should run the cron?

Within the specification of Expedia (http://developer.ean.com/spec/) it is stated that there is a limitations of the number of requests:
 - Hotel List Requests: 5000:1 
 - Room Availability Requests: 500:1

It will be very much helpful for me if I am able to know how to speed up the website.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. Cron jobs and caching to local database sounds like a good idea to me. Just set the cron to a similar interval that the content changes at the different hotel sites. If performance is crucial, perhaps have the cache database on it's own server.

Comment: My bad, this was supposed to be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for answering, no issues, I want an answer seriously. I am stuck here for last 2 weeks!

Comment: Problem with the cron is that, there are thousand of cities, how much data should be fetched in the database and how many times because hotels are booked in next 1 hour approx. If we run the cron job, and suppose hotel was booked which was fetched and saved in the database, in that case how should i manage this.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, that's a hard one to answer. I suppose you could add an extra validation: when a user wants to book a hotel (with information from your cache), make 1 extra api call with that specific hotel that the user  clicked. If it's still available, job done. If it's not available: update cache & send a response to the user.

Comment: I am really sorry Liren! Can you please refresh the page and see the modified question for me once again please?

Comment: PS: I would probbably create a simple solution for this to begin with and then generate statistics over the failrate and code specifically to that. If the fail rate is 1%, that's probably not bad. If it's at 80%, you still got work to do. Obviously taking some "Value of a customer" * Failrate > "Cost of implementation" into consideration.

Comment: "how much data should be fetched in the database and how many times because hotels are booked in next 1 hour approx": If you suspect the cache only to be valid for max 1 hour, set the cron to work each hour? Are you only basing this on assumption though? I would test this if I were you to get some real world data and adjust to that.

Comment: But Liren, I am quite confused here. If there are 100 million cities then I have to run cron for each and every date and also there are some cases. Cases are: search for hotel in New York for 2 adults, 1 children from 1st August checkin time to 8th August. Are you understanding the scenario? I was thinking to run the cron job, but the question was for how many cases should I run the cron?

Answer (score 2):

Amuk, try to use curl_multi. It's a great way to process multiple HTTP requests in parallel in PHP. curl_multi is particularly handy when working with large data sets (like fetching thousands of RSS feeds at one time) http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

Comment: the article might be a bit old, but the the library is used by trivago and the rest https://github.com/joshfraser/rolling-curl